# Way to import library in a solidity smartcontract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, openzeppelin, import

I am studying smart contracts and I have looked at some popular projects on GithHub.

I have seen imports like this:

```
 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

and like that:

```
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

I do not understand the difference between these 2 methods for importing the SafeMath library.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new and correct way of importing the package is the top import that you posted:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

The bottom way is the old package. It is not recommended to use that one, as it may not be up-to-date.